# How to develop a function

Tags: pandas, list, csv, numpy, matrix

I am completely new in python and I am learning it. I have written the following code but i couldnt make any functions of it. Can somebody help me please?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
f = open('1.csv', 'r')
df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[0], sep="\t", index_col=False)
Primary_List = df.values.tolist()
x = 0
y = len(Primary_List)
for i in range(x, y):
x = i
MyMatrix = Primary_List[x:x + 10]
print(MyMatrix)
```

Comment: You mean like you want to define a function in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function where you pass in the filename, then you could use this code to read and print many csv files.

```
def createMatrix(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    df = pd.read_csv(f, usecols=[0], sep="\t", index_col=False)
    Primary_List = df.values.tolist()
    x = 0
    y = len(Primary_List)
    for i in range(x, y):
    x = i
    MyMatrix = Primary_List[x:x + 10]
    return MyMatrix

print(createMatrix('1.csv'))
print(createMatrix('2.csv'))
print(createMatrix('3.csv'))
```